# Calculate the limit of a piecewise function equal to a fraction and zero

Tags: calculus, limits

The question asks to calculate the limit of the following function:
[image]

I'm struggling to figure out how to approach this? Should I approach it from the left hand side first of $-1$ and then the right hand side? It is hard to say since $x=-1$ is not included in the first expression.

Comment: "*Should I approach it from the left hand side first and then the right hand side?*"  Yes, that is fine.  "*It is hard to say since $x$ is not included in the first expression*"  What do you mean $x$ is not included in the first expression?  Even if it weren't, what would that matter?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question, I meant to say since $x=-1$ is not included.

Comment: If it helps you to see, you can rewrite the function as $\begin{cases}\frac{x^4-1}{x+1}&\text{if}~x<-1\\0&\text{if}~x=-1\\\frac{x^4-1}{x+1}&\text{if}~x>-1\end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we talk about limit at $-1$, we don't look at what happens at $-1$, we look at what happens around $-1$, so the limit is just
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}\dfrac{x^{4}-1}{x+1}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}\dfrac{(x^{2}-1)(x^{2}+1)}{x+1}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}\dfrac{(x+1)(x-1)(x^{2}+1)}{x+1}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}(x-1)(x^{2}+1)\\
&=-4.
\end{align*}